# Can a bone be not keyframable?

Tags: rigging, bones, keyframes

is there a way to have bones that cant be keyframed? for example: a slider that hides/un-hides parts of the armature, it would make no sense to have that enabled for keyframing, or it could be annoying to deal with if animated by accident while automeyframe was on.

Comment: you can hide bones in pose mode if select them then press "h" and reveal them by pressing "alt+h"

Comment: the idea is to have the bone visible since id be moving it constantly to hide/unhide the armature, but it wouldnt want for the armature to disappear randomly in the timeline because of an accidental keyframe